# List of lists (not just list) in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to make a list of lists in python.

My code is below.

```
import csv
f = open('agGDPpct.csv','r')
inputfile = csv.DictReader(f)

list = []

next(f) ##Skip first line (column headers)

for line in f:
    array = line.rstrip().split(",")
    list.append(array[1])
    list.append(array[0])
    list.append(array[53])
    list.append(array[54])
    list.append(array[55])
    list.append(array[56])
    list.append(array[57])
print list
```

I'm pulling only select columns from every row. My code pops this all into one list, as such:

```
['ABW', 'Aruba', '0.506252445', '0.498384331', '0.512418427', '', '', 'AND', 'Andorra', '', '', '', '', '', 'AFG', 'Afghanistan', '30.20560247', '27.09154001', '24.50744042', '24.60324707', '23.96716227'...]
```

But what I want is a list in which each row is its own list: `[[a,b,c][d,e,f][g,h,i]...]` Any tips?

Comment: `list.append([array[1],array[0],array[53], etc])`

Comment: As a side note, you probably want to use the `csv` module. Here you import it and create a `DictReader()` object, but then proceed to read directly from your file handle and manually split on commas.

Comment: Typing in your title into a random search engine gave me this: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2000-January/000946.html

Comment: Thanks! @Tim works great √+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Make all your desired inputs into a list before appending. Try this:

```
import csv 
with open('agGDPpct.csv','r') as f:
  inputfile = csv.DictReader(f)
  list = []

  for line in inputfile: 
    list.append([line[1], line[0], line[53], line[54], line[55], line[56], line[57]])
print list
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized I'm screwing up the reader code. But when I try your suggestion I get a Key Error:1 seemingly related to the .append line.

Comment: I figured out the problem: Key Error wants the default fieldnames from the first row (e.g. "first name", "last name", etc.), not the column numbers 1, 2, etc. I figured that much but it still wouldn't work. The problem seems to be the "next(f)". Remove this and the code works. Maybe it was skipping the fieldnames, not sure.

Comment: That absolutely was the problem. You used next(f) when not using the csv class, using the csv class obviates the need to use next(f) since when you declare a DictReader, it uses the first row as header names. Good job figuring that out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Referring to https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Instead of

```
for line in f:
```

Write

```
for line in inputfile:
```

2. And also use `list.append([array[1],array[0],array[53],..])` to append a list to a list.
3. One more thing, referring to https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next , use  `inputfile.next()` instead of `next(f)` .

After these changes, you get:

```
import csv
f = open('agGDPpct.csv','r')
inputfile = csv.DictReader(f)

list = []

inputfile.next() ##Skip first line (column headers)  

for line in inputfile:
    list.append([array[1],array[0],array[53],array[54],array[55],array[56],array[57]])
print list
```

In addition to that, it is not a good practice to use `list` as a variable name as it is a reserved word for the data structure of the same name. Rename that too.

You can further improve the above code using `with` . I will leave that to you.

Try and see if it works.

Comment: Why? Reader object has been stored in inputfile I suppose? See https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: You changed your answer quite a bit.. anyway the reader already splits by comma, you don't have to do that manually

Comment: Thanks @TimCastelijns ! Edited the answer. And I still maintain that inputfile will work in for loop and not f :)

Comment: Thanks for this. When I try it it says 'array' is undefined however.

Answer (score 0):

To end up with a list of lists, you have to make the inner lists with the columns from each row that you want, and then append *that list* to the outer one. Something like:

```
for line in f:
    array = line.rstrip().split(",")
    inner = []
    inner.append(array[1])
    # ...
    inner.append(array[57])
    list.append(inner)
```

Note that it's also not a good practice to use the name of the type ("`list`") as a variable name -- this is called "shadowing", and it means that if you later try to call `list(...)` to convert something to a list, you'll get an error because you're trying to call a particular *instance* of a list, not the `list` built-in.

Answer (score 0):

To build on `csv` module capabilities, I'll do

```
import csv
f = csv.reader(open('your.csv'))
next(f)

list_of_lists = [items[1::-1]+items[53:58] for items in f]
```

Note that

- `items` *is a list of items*, thanks to the intervention of a `csv.reader()` object;
- using slice addressing returns sublists taken from `items`, so that the `+` operator in this context means concatenation of lists
- the first slice expression `1::-1`means *from 1* go *to the beginning* moving *backwards*, or `[items[1], items[0]]`.

Comment: Interesting, my first encounter with this code but it works perfectly. Thanks!